# Use function inside subroutine in FORTRAN77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am updating legacy code and I need to use a simple mathematical function inside a subroutine. I cannot figure out how to do this. I have a function that *works* when called from a test program. What do I need to do differently for a subroutine?

example:

```
subroutine foo(i,j,k)

i = bar(j,k)

stuff = otherstuff

return 
end
```

other info:
bar is an erf approximation.
I am using the PGF90 compiler.
I am new to FORTRAN from C.

thanks!

Comment: What is the exact problem you're encountering? Do you get an error message? During compiling? During linking? When running the program? Be more specific than "I have a problem".

Answer (score 3):

Basically, calling from a program or a subroutine shouldn't differ. Does the code really look like this, without any declarations? This means all variables will have implicit types: variables with names starting with the letters i-n will be integer, all others real; this also holds for function return values. The code you show, tries to assign a real (`bar()`) to an integer (`i`).

If you're writing new code, **always** start programs and procedures with `IMPLICIT NONE`. This forces you to explicitly include type declarations for all variables and function return values, greatly reducing errors.